# Retrofit все время failure

Tags: android, json, аннотации

**Что делаю:**

Отправляю POST-запрос на сервер с помощью Retrofit 1.9.

***API:***

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/auth/registration")
void register(
        @Field("name") String name,
        @Field("surname") String surname,
        @Field("password") String password,
        Callback<RegisterResponseNew> response);
```

***Отправка запроса:***

```
            RestWorker.getInstance().register(
                    "Name",
                    "LastName",
                    "pass",
                    new Callback<RegisterResponseNew>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(RegisterResponseNew registerResponseNew, Response response) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                        }
                    });
```

***В ответ я должен получить такой JSON:***

```
{
  "status": "stat",
  "status_code": "000",
  "data": {
    "name": [
      "some name"
    ]
  }
}
```

***Вот мои POJO:***

```
public class RegisterResponseNew {

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("status_code")
    private String statusCode;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private RegisterDataNew data;
}



public class RegisterDataNew {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

}
```

**Проблема:**

Запрос постоянно failure, но если убрать из класса `RegisterResponseNew`

```
    @SerializedName("data")
    private RegisterDataNew data;
```

Тогда будет, как и надо, проходить в success.

В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Expose` это аннотация из библиотеки `GSon`. Данной аннотацией обозначаются поля, которые должны быть сериализованы/десериализованны. Однако это работает если объект Gson был создан с помощью билдера, т.е. так:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()
```

Если объект был создан так:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

то данная аннотация не будет иметь эффекта.

Работает это так: если есть класс с такой структурой:

```
public class User {
   @Expose private String firstName;
   @Expose(serialize = false) private String lastName;
   @Expose (serialize = false, deserialize = false) private String emailAddress;
   private String password;
 }
```

То с использованием `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` поле `password` не будет сериализовано и десериализовано, так же не будут сериализованы поля `lastName` и `emailAddress`, т.к. у них стоит флаг `serialize = false`, плюс ко всему поле`emailAddress` не будет десериализованно, т.к. у него стоит флаг `deserialize = false`.

Того же самого эффекта можно достичь используя ключевое слово `transient` перед полями которые не нужно сериализовывать/десериализовывать.

Взято из [официальной документации](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html).

**UPD**: класс `RegisterDataNew` должен быть таким, т.к. тип у поля `name` - `JsonArray`, следовательно он не может конвертировать `JsonArray` в тип `String`, из-за чего и вылетает ошибка. Кстати в логах это должно быть отражено.

```
public class RegisterDataNew {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private List<String> nameList;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я читал эту доку, но немного не понял. Сейчас дополню вопрос..

Comment: @researcher дополнил ответ

Comment: @researcher кстати я думаю следовало бы задать новый вопрос, т.к. после редактирования он полностью поменял суть, из-за чего первоначальный ответ кажется бессмысленным

Comment: Спасибо за решение!